# Why don't my Wix forms work, and return a 504 error on form submission?

Tags: velo, http-status-code-504

I've got a series of Wix forms on our site, and somehow in the last few weeks, since our last round of testing, all our forms have stopped working. When a user clicks "submit", the button goes grey (correct behaviour), then stays like that and doesn't return a success message, and doesn't log the entry into the submission database. I don't see any errors in the console, but when I check the Network tab, there's a POST request to /_api/wix-forms/v1/submit-form with a 504. I tried deleting the forms, and rebuilding from scratch, and had the same issue.

I modified all the settings in Wix that I could think of, and deleted the forms and built new ones, but still no luck.